# jQuery Script To Hide Parent Not Working - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, parent-child

In Wordpress, for some reason, I cannot get this jQuery to work although it's working via [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MikeRS/9LT7t/) with my jQuery version 1.11 (that I am using and it's working on other instances on my site). I'm not sure if it's a conflict, and if so I cannot find it, or if I just need to write this in plain JavaScript, which I'm unsure of the proper coding for.

As you can see in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MikeRS/9LT7t/) when you change the library to jQuery 1.11.0 the script works however in plain JS it does not.

My conflict is I'm using

```
$(function(){
    $('div.tabcontents > div').each(function(index){
        var innerView = $(this).find('div[class^="view"]');
        var innerHtml = $(innerView).html();
        if(innerHtml.trim() == ''){
            $(this).hide();
            $('ul.tabs').find('li').eq(index).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

on the same page which I fear is causing the issues but still unclear as to why

```
$(".view1:empty").parent().hide();
$(".view2:empty").parent().hide();
$(".view3:empty").parent().hide();
$(".view4:empty").parent().hide();
$(".view5:empty").parent().hide();
```

is not working at all either.

My HTML would render to the following:

```
<div class="tabcontents noScreen">
<div id="view1">
<h2>OVERVIEW</h2>
<div class="view1">Your bones don't break, mine do. That's clear.</div>
</div>

<div id="view2">
<h2>EXPERIENCE</h2>
<div class="view2"></div>
</div>

<div id="view3">
<h2>PUBLICATIONS</h2>
<div class="view3"></div>
</div>

<div id="view4">
<h2>COMMUNITY</h2>
<div class="view4">They called me Mr Glass.</div>
</div>

<div id="view5">
<h2>RECOGNITION</h2>
<div class="view5"></div>
</div>

</div>

<script>
$(".view1:empty").parent().hide();
$(".view2:empty").parent().hide();
$(".view3:empty").parent().hide();
$(".view4:empty").parent().hide();
$(".view5:empty").parent().hide();

//or

$(function(){
    $('div.tabcontents > div').each(function(index){
        var innerView = $(this).find('div[class^="view"]');
        var innerHtml = $(innerView).html();
        if(innerHtml.trim() == ''){
            $(this).hide();
            $('view').find('h2').eq(index).hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

What am I missing here?

I cannot get the jQuery to work on the page in Wordpress. Standalone, as seen on JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/MikeRS/9LT7t/) it's working just fine using the jQuery 1.11.0 library that I have enqueued in my theme. Is there a plain JS I can use in place of this? Or if it's conflicting, which I'm not seeing any errors, could it be due to the other and similar jQuery already being used?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Do you see any console errors?

Comment: Also, all your `hide()` functions could be combined if you'd put a common class on those elements.

Comment: Also also, nice dummy text. I assume it's literary in origin, but still...

Comment: last line .. $('view') .. missing a dot $('.view') AND $('.view') is looking for a element with a class="view" but if you have an ID="view1" you have to write $('#view1')... and I have no idea what :empty is. what is it?

Comment: I cannot get the jQuery to work on the page. Is there a plain JS I can use in place of this? Or if it's conflicting, which I'm not seeing any errors, could it be due to the other and similar jQuery already being used?

Comment: @caramba: what would I use for #view* so div id=view then anything after view?

Comment: @caramba: The :empty selector selects empty elements. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_empty.asp

Comment: you should use a class then and maybe iterate trough it with .each()

Comment: I'm already using class...

Comment: The issue isn't the code not working. It's the code not working within Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `jQuery` in place of `$`.  Wordpress by default uses [noconflict](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/), so that is most likely this issue.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. Could it be where the script is living within the code (aka its placement)?

Comment: Maybe, try wrapping the code in `jQuery(function() { /* your code here*/ });` and see if that helps - it will make it wait until the document is ready.

Comment: I tried that as well. Is it possible to combine already working jQuery with the new jQuery. So add 
'$(".view1:empty").parent().hide();
$(".view2:empty").parent().hide();
$(".view3:empty").parent().hide();
$(".view4:empty").parent().hide();
$(".view5:empty").parent().hide();' 

with 

'$(function(){
    $('div.tabcontents > div').each(function(index){
        var innerView = $(this).find('div[class^="view"]');
        var innerHtml = $(innerView).html();
        if(innerHtml.trim() == ''){
            $(this).hide();
            $('ul.tabs').find('li').eq(index).hide();
        }
    });
});'